# Design of shared Acceptance Tests steps for different test frameworks and languages

Tags: automated-testing, cucumber, bdd

We have the following setup:

Multiple client applications containing UI E2E tests written in different programming languages (java, c#, swift ...).
All those client applications have basically same Backend.

For all e2e tests in various project we always use BDD approach for tests (even for testing backend) - basically using cucumber for defining features, scenarios and steps

**Now to the question**

In our client tests we would like to be able to execute steps from BE tests ( to get Backend to some state).

The problem is that client tests and Backend tests are usually in different programming languages.

- is this something you are already familiar with, have you already handled this
- is there some 3rd party tool to handle this ? I have not found anything
- have you implemented some custom solution for this?

Only solution that comes up to my mind is creating Rest service inside BE tests - and client tests triggering correct steps

**Why?**

With a diverse landscape of technologies and products we face a need of re-writing essential parts of tests (steps) in every product's test automation framework teams are using - C#, Cypress or Swift. We want to do it smarter.

Comment: Please expand on the problem you need to solve.  You say that client and backend tests are written in different frameworks and languages. Please give more detail on the specific problems that this is causing to your organization. I can speculate on several myself but it would be better if you gave more details for your situation.

Comment: Note that Cucumber has been implemented in most languages if you want it to be the common tool.